# Can't run xctests using @import

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xctest

I'm trying to run my iOS swift app tests but can't make it run. I have it working manually adding files to my tests target but now I'm trying to use Xcode 7 @import and I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
```

- I've checked main target creates module is enabled
- Also checked testability is enabled and Host application with "Allow testing Host Application APIs" is enabled in test target

I'm using cocoapods, building in all the targets. I've a bridging header declared in both targets.

Is there anything I'm missing. Why can't I run my tests :(